Why does my visual studio code(vscode) terminal output "^c?

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

I set it up and ran it for the first time to do cpp from Windows to vscode. I downloaded mingw, set environment variables, and set edit configuration. There is no problem with the compilation itself, but the first compile to boot doesn't output ^c, and after that, it outputs ^c on every attempt.
It's the same with any simple code compilation, like the code above.
This is how it is output to the terminal:
PS C:\test> ^C
PS C:\test> 
PS C:\test>  & 'c:\Users\vlvkr\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.22.11-win32-x64\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe' '--stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-xvviozod.yof' '--stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-1ldecrxx.ppt' '--stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-cq4di2ly.3xz' '--pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-wbjzxtdl.txs' '--dbgExe=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gdb.exe' '--interpreter=mi'
test
PS C:\test>

I deleted and re-installed Visual Studio Code and mingw, but it hasn't changed. I just want it printed on terminal normally without ^C.

I have a question. Why do you use the & when executing the program?

sorry, i didn't do it on purpose. how can i remove it?

Try to executing the program, without the &, maybe it helps

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

For beginners, I strongly recommend using Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition instead of Visual Studio Code and MinGW.

VSCode does that. It seems like a very minor complaint to me but if you want it to stop then don't use VSCode. As stated above you might be happier with Visual Studio instead, it's a bit cleaner, and it's definitely easier for beginners.

I deleted and re-installed Visual Studio Code and mingw, but it hasn't changed. In the distant past (before windows 95) this used to help however in more recent times reinstalling usually doesn't do anything useful. For one reason is your settings usually are not deleted between uninstalling and reinstalling because they are not saved in the same location as the software.

@MarekR why link to that MSO post? their very first revision has the textual version.
